# Connect two classes

Tags: java, class

I'm stuck on this question, I have one class called book and another class called  author

In the book class I have title, author, price and ISBN

In author class I have first name, second name and nationality

the question is to connect the author class with book class ......

TestClass--------

```
public class BookTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        Author fullAuth = new Author("Bob", "Marly", "Russian");
        Book bookInf = new Book("Alice", fullAuth ,60000,2000);
        Student studInf = new Student("Ted", "21/10/1992", "Male","Simmonds Close 63","King Close 65","Computing", 12000);

        System.out.println(fullAuth.getAuNational() +" "+ fullAuth.getAuFname ());
        System.out.println(bookInf.getTitle() +" "+ bookInf.getPrice());
        System.out.println(studInf.getName() +" "+ studInf.getName ());
    }
}
```

Book Class------------

```
public class Book{

    private double price;
    private int isbn;
    private String title;
    private String author;

    public Book (String title, String author, double price, int isbn){
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public void setTitleBook(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public void setPriceBook(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;

    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
    public int getAuthor() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(int isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
    public int getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }   
}
```

Author Class----------

```
public class Author{

    private String auFname;
    private String auSname;
    private String auNational;

    public Author (String auFname, String auSname, String auNational){

        this.auFname = auFname;
        this.auFname = auSname;
        this.auNational = auNational;
    }

    public String getAuFname() {
        return auFname;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String auFname) {
        this.auFname = auFname;
    }

    public String getAuSname() {
        return auSname;
    }
    public void setSecondName(String auSname) {
        this.auSname = auSname;
    }

    public String getAuNational() {
        return auNational;
    }
    public void setAuNational(String auNational) {
        this.auNational = auNational;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript, I removed the wrong tag.

Comment: Every time I see a question that contains book ISBN I assume it's a homework question. I feel sorry for people who actually work in the publishing / library industries and encounter problems.

Comment: I don't like the "au" prefix on Author data members.  Get rid of that.  The first constructor for Book is wrong - you only need the second one.  What about books with more than one Author?

Comment: I have the author in the book class and I want that the book class use the information from the Author class, maybe use extension or ...

Comment: @Bob You are already using `Author` in your `Book` class. What is it you really want?

Comment: Design (using a class diagram) and build an Author class to contain information about an Author, for example the firstname, lastname and nationality. Then modify the Book class so that a book contains a single author object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor in class `Book` should look like this:

```
public Book (String title, Author author, double price, int isbn){
    this.author = author;
    this.title = title;
    this.price = price;
    this.isbn = isbn;
}
```

And also in main do

```
Book bookInf = new Book("Alice", fullAuth ,60000,2000);
```

Change

```
public int getAuthor() {
    return isbn;
}
```

To

```
public Author getAuthor() {
    return author;
}
```

### Full code

#### BookTest.java

```
public class BookTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Author fullAuth = new Author("Bob", "Marly", "Russian");
        Book bookInf = new Book("Alice", fullAuth, 60000, 2000);
        //Student studInf = new Student("Ted", "21/10/1992", "Male", "Simmonds Close 63", "King Close 65", "Computing", 12000);

        System.out.println(fullAuth.getAuNational() + " " + fullAuth.getAuFname());
        System.out.println(bookInf.getTitle() + " " + bookInf.getPrice());
        //System.out.println(studInf.getName() + " " + studInf.getName());


    }
}
```

#### Book.java

```
public class Book {

    private double price;
    private int isbn;
    private String title;
    private Author author;

    public Book(Author a) {
        author = a;
    }

    public Book(String title, Author author, double price, int isbn) {
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public void setTitleBook(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setPriceBook(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setAuthor(Author author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public Author getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setIsbn(int isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public int getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }
}
```

#### Author.java

```
public class Author {

    private String auFname;
    private String auSname;
    private String auNational;

    public Author(String auFname, String auSname, String auNational) {
        this.auFname = auFname;
        this.auFname = auSname;
        this.auNational = auNational;
    }

    public String getAuFname() {
        return auFname;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String auFname) {
        this.auFname = auFname;
    }

    public String getAuSname() {
        return auSname;
    }

    public void setSecondName(String auSname) {
        this.auSname = auSname;
    }

    public String getAuNational() {
        return auNational;
    }

    public void setAuNational(String auNational) {
        this.auNational = auNational;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had it at the first time

Comment: @BobMarny See edit. You may have other errors to, but this is correct way to write the contructor

Comment: I think so too, and I have done it already, i just miss understanding where the other errors are....

Comment: And if I do it in this way, parameter author in the book class haven't used

Comment: new Book("Alice", fullAuth ,60000,2000);   This part underlined wirh a red

Comment: @BobMarny  In the constructor you still have  `public Book (String title, String author, double price, int isbn){`. Change it to `public Book(String title, Author author, double price, int isbn) {`. `author` is `Author` not `String`

Comment: That's cool and start working, BUT after I want the result to display it show me Author@57530551 this.

Comment: Do something like `System.out.println(bookInf.getAuthor().getAuSname());`, where `bookInf` is the `Book` object

Comment: THANK YOU, I get this now!!!!

Comment: @Bob Marny, you should write a toString method in eqach of those classes so that you can easily get the details. like in Author have a method that returns a string that consists of getfirstname() + getlastname(), etc, and then in your book class, you can call it on the Author object as author.toString()

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
Book bookInf = new Book("Alice", author ,60000,2000);
```

to this

```
Book bookInf = new Book("Alice", fullAuth ,60000,2000);
```

and change this:

```
Author a = new Author(author, author, author);
```

to this:

```
this.author = author; //author being the parameter
```

Comment: doesn't work I have tried this ((

Comment: i'm editing, you have to change the book constructor too, to take the parameter

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to import the Author class into the Book class?

Then it would just be

import "package".Author;

Answer (score -2):

If you are asking how to retrieve the author information from the book instance, then you can get that using

```
bookInf.getAuthor().getAuFname()
```

or

```
bookInf.getAuthor().getAuSname()
```

However, you will have to modify the getAuthor method of the Book class first, as it is returning isbn instead of author. Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, someone read the question... NOT. All you say is already there.

Comment: Missed that completely. My bad.